# How to monitor parallel mapping a function over a list?

Tags: monitoring, parallelization

For instance, how to monitor the progress of `ParallelMap[function, list]`?

Comment: Short answer: you can't without losing performance.  Long answer contained in a duplicate, which I'm going to post shortly.

Comment: I guess that's the same for ParallelDo/Map/etc...?

Comment: No.  There's no good way that I know of to monitor `Map`.  But it's trivial to replace it with a `Table`.